# All my components share a similar state and I would like them to have their own state

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state, android-room

I am currently working on a small project to understand the functionality and implementation of Room. So far, I have made good progress.

However, I am facing an issue with the checkbox state. Whenever I click on it, the state of all the checkboxes in all the added notes change. I believe this is due to a problem with general and local state, but I am unable to find a solution on my own.

I hope I have explained my problem clearly.

Here are the different parts of my code:

```
@Entity("notes")
data class Note(
    val task: String,
    val isChecked: Boolean,
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int = 0
)
```

```
data class NoteState(
    val noteId: Int = 0,
    val notes: List<Note> = emptyList(),
    val task: String = "",
    val isAddingTask: Boolean = false,
    val isNotChecked: Boolean = false
)
```

```
sealed interface NoteEvents {
    object SaveNotes: NoteEvents
    data class SetTask(val task: String) : NoteEvents
    object ShowDialog: NoteEvents
    object HideDialog: NoteEvents
    data class IsCheckNote(val noteId: Int): NoteEvents
    data class DeleteNote(val note: Note) : NoteEvents
}
```

```
class NoteViewModel(
    private val dao: NoteDao
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _notes = dao.getNotes()
        .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(), emptyList())

    private val _state = MutableStateFlow(NoteState())
    val state = combine(_state, _notes) { state, notes ->
        state.copy(
            notes = notes
        )
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), NoteState())


    fun onEvent(event: NoteEvents) {
        when(event) {
            NoteEvents.SaveNotes -> {
                val task = state.value.task
                val isChecked = state.value.isNotChecked

                if (task.isBlank()) return

                val note = Note(
                    task = task,
                    isChecked = isChecked
                )
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.upsertNote(note)
                }
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        isAddingTask = false,
                        task = "",
                        isNotChecked = false
                    )
                }
            }
            is NoteEvents.SetTask -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(task = event.task)
                }
            }
            is NoteEvents.DeleteNote -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.deleteNote(note = event.note)
                }
            }
            is NoteEvents.IsCheckNote -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(isNotChecked = !it.isNotChecked)
                }
            }
            NoteEvents.ShowDialog -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(isAddingTask = true)
                }
            }
            NoteEvents.HideDialog -> {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(isAddingTask = false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NoteScreen(
    state: NoteState,
    onEvent: (NoteEvents) -> Unit,
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
             TopAppBar(
                 title = {
                     Text(
                         text = "EYE NOTE",
                         fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
                         textAlign = TextAlign.Center
                     )
                 }
             )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = {
                onEvent(NoteEvents.ShowDialog)
            }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "Add note"
                )
            }
        },

    ) { paddingValues ->

        if(state.isAddingTask) {
            AddNoteDialog(state = state, onEvent = onEvent)
        }

        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = paddingValues,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(start = 20.dp, end = 20.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(20.dp)
        ) {
            items(state.notes) { note ->
                NoteBox(
                    task = note.task,
                    delete = {
                        onEvent(NoteEvents.DeleteNote(note))
                    },
                    isChecked = state.isNotChecked,
                    onCheckChange = {
                        onEvent(NoteEvents.IsCheckNote(note.id))
                    }
                )
            }
        }

    }

}

@Composable
fun NoteBox(
    task: String,
    isChecked: Boolean,
    onCheckChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    delete: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        shadowElevation = 5.dp,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20)
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer
                )
                .padding(start = 5.dp)
        ) {
            Checkbox(
                checked = isChecked,
                onCheckedChange = onCheckChange
            )
            Text(
                text = task,
                fontSize = 14.sp,
                modifier = modifier.weight(1f)
            )

            IconButton(
                onClick = delete
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Delete,
                    contentDescription = "Delete note"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I tried to tinker with the Note ID without success.

Comment: You are passing an id of the note to the event isCheckNote and yet you are not using it anywhere in the when block of viewModel. Also a better to do all of this is to directly create a fun in your DAO that update the isChecked boolean of the note with specific id you pase to it as argument.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks I'll see that.

Comment: If you can't figure out how just tell me and i will post a detailed answer

Comment: If you don't mind, I think it would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an `id` of the note to the event `isCheckNote` and yet you are not using it anywhere in the `when` block of `viewModel`.

In order to do this all you have to do is whenever you click on a `checkbox` you have to **insert a new note to the database** but with the same id, and configure you **conflict startegy** to automatically replace any inserted note with same id.

so you dao has to be something like:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertNote(note : Note)
```

Then in your viewModel your isCheckNote event(I don't like this name i would personally name it onNoteCheck or onCheckNote) should be like:

```
is NoteEvents.IsCheckNote -> {
      viewModelScope.launch{noteId->
      //I'm assuming you have your notes in list you can edit this as it suits you.
val noteToUpdate = notes.find{note->
                     note.id == noteId
                   }
noteToUpdate?.let{note->
          dao.insertNote(
          //this returns the note that you checked but with the isChecked changed
          note.copy(isChecked = !note.isChecked)
          )
         }
      }
   }
```

Here is a [**repository**](https://github.com/philipplackner/MVVMTodoApp/tree/master) for a similar app by [**philipp Lackner**](https://www.youtube.com/@PhilippLackner) but with more advanced best practices(MVVM, koltin Channels...), and he made a video about it.

**Note: this not tested if it works because i don't have the whole project but the logic remains the same.**

Comment: "I sincerely thank you. I will look into the matter and come back to you to tell you what it is about. I will also watch Philipp Lackner's video. I follow his channel but I didn't think to check out what he had to say on the subject."